# How to group individual values from an existing variable into a new variable in R

Tags: r, data-science

I'm new to R and I'm stuck. I'm working on a health dataset with each row as one patient's information.

I have a variable called diag_codes. It has the patient's medical condition in the form of a diagnostic code/number. I want to group the individual condition codes into broader categories (heart disease, resp disease, liver disease) and make that a new variable.

E.g. I know that 1,2,3,4,84 are all respiratory diseases. I also know that 5, 6, 7, 32, 56 are all cardiovascular diseases. I want to create a new variable called diagnosis.

| diag_code | diagnosis |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "resp disease" |
| 2 | "resp disease" |
| 56 | "CVD disease" |
| 3 | "resp disease" |
| 4 | "resp disease" |
| 84 | "resp disease" |
| 5 | "CVD disease" |
| 6 | "CVD disease" |
| 7 | "CVD disease" |
| 32 | "CVD disease" |

I have tried to use case_when() and mutate(), or ifelse() and mutate(), but they usually involve a single true or false condition.

I want to be able to do something like this (I know this is incorrect):

```
data <- data %>%
mutate(diagnosis = case_when(diag_code==c(1,2,3,5,84)) ~ "Resp disease",
                   case_when(diag_code==c(5,6,7,32,56)) ~ "CVD disease", 
                   TRUE ~ "Unknown)
```

Comment: Use, for example, `diag_code %in% c(1,2,3,5,84)`, not `diag_code==c(1,2,3,5,84)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that you need to correct to make it work:

First, you can use only one `case_when()` statement and second, when you want to evaluate a vector you can use `%in%` instead of `==`. This then should look like this:

```r
data <- data %>%
mutate(diagnosis = case_when(diag_code %in% c(1,2,3,5,84) ~ "Resp disease",
                             diag_code %in% c(5,6,7,32,56) ~ "CVD disease", 
                             TRUE ~ "Unknown)
```